# i am getting this error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security

Thank you for your time:Could you please provide me my error.I am getting an error on dependecies tag stating "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." Please provide your valuable comments .

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the diagnostics is about the fact, that XML document must have only one root element. So the provided sample is not a valid XML document.

Comment: What do i do to make it a valid XML doc.   Thank you

Comment: To keep only one root node, now you have 2: properties and dependencies. I do not know your actual format, but to make it valid XML you can for example keep only one of them or to incorporate the both into another node.

Comment: I have remove the properties tag from the code but now its coming on <spring.version>3.5.1.RELEASE</spring.version>

Comment: But it means that you kept the contents of "properties" node and still have several root nodes (jdk.version, spring.version and others). You need to completely remove properties with all contents to make it work. Or to add just one node including both "properties" and "dependencies"

Comment: There must be a single root element. Wrap something around both the `<properties>` and `<dependencies>` trees, or move one into the other. (XML Document Fragments can have multiple top-level elements, but they can't be parsed directly by most XML parsers; they must be included into another document via an Entity Reference.)